# How to extend AFNetworking 2.0 to perform request combining

Tags: afnetworking-2

I have a UI where the same image URL could be requested by several UIImageViews at varying times. Obviously if a request from one of them has finished then returning the cached version works as expected. However, especially with slower networks, I'd like to be able to piggy-back requests for an image URL onto any currently running/waiting HTTP request for the same URL.

On an HTTP server this called request combining and I'd love to do the same in the client - to combine the different requests for the same URL into a single request and then callback separately to each of the callers). The requests for that URL dont happen to start at the same time.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

I think re-writing UIImageView+AFNetworking might be the easiest way:

- check the af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue to see if it has an operation with the same request
- if I do already have an operation in the queue or running then add myself to some list of callbacks/blocks to be called on success/failure
- if I don't have the operation, then create it as normal
- in the setCompletionBlockWithSuccess to call each of the blocks in turn.

Any simpler alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and decided that your way was the most straightforward. One added bit of complexity is that these downloads require special credentials and so must go through their own operation queue. Here's the code from my UIImageView category to check whether a particular URL is inflight:

```
NSUInteger foundOperation = [[ConnectionManager sharedConnectionManager].operationQueue.operations indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(AFHTTPRequestOperation *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    BOOL URLAlreadyInFlight = [obj.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:URL.absoluteString];
    if (URLAlreadyInFlight) {
        NSBlockOperation *updateUIOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                self.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] cachedImageForURL:URL];
            }];
        }];
        //Makes updating the UI dependent on the completion of the matching operation.
        [updateUIOperation addDependency:obj];
    }

    return URLAlreadyInFlight;
}];
```

Were you able to come up with a better solution?

EDIT: Well, it looks like my method of updating the UI just can't work, as the operation's completion blocks are run asynchronously, so the operation finishes before the blocks are run. However, I was able to modify the image cache to be able to add callbacks for when certain URLs are cached, which seems to work correctly. So this method will properly detect when certain URLs are in flight and be able to take action with that knowledge.